# Integrating using scipy's trapz function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm currently trying to integrate a function which consists of XY point pairs. Feel free to take a look: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2635172/example.csv

I'm using pandas to read the file

```
data_df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", sep="\t", index_col=0, names=["test"])
```

If you look closely, the spacing between consecutive x values are identical, therefore I can write the integral as following:

```
integral = integrate.trapz(data_df.values.transpose())*data_df.index[1]
```

where `integrate` is imported from scipy and `data_df.index[1]` refers to the spacing. The following value is returned: 189274.48501691

If I perform the integration the following way:

```
  integrate.trapz(data_df.values.transpose(), x=data_df.index)
```

A completely different value is returned (5.846689e+08). Any ideas why this is the case?

Note that the first result should be correct. This is also returned by MATLAB's trapz function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the values from the `Index` instance:

```
integrate.trapz(data_df.values.transpose(), x=data_df.index.values)
#[189274.48501691408]
```

It also works If you transform your `data_df.index` from `Index` to `ndarray`:

```
integrate.trapz(data_df.values.transpose(), x=data_df.index.view(pd.np.ndarray))
#[189274.48501691408]
```

Comment: Thanks! What values are used when I only pass the data_df.index object?

Comment: It is also an array, but its behaviour is somehow incompatible with the integration function. I've opened [as issue in GitHub for this question](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3992), thank you!